# Viewing Semigroups as Categories?

Tags: category-theory, semigroups, monoid

I am wondering how to view semigroups as categories. For example, we can easily view monoids as categories with a single object. Unfortunately, semigroups do not necessarily have identities, so the same view does not work with semigroups.

However, I did come across **[this idea](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semigroup#attitudes_toward_semigroups)** where one adjoins a new element to a semigroup and treats it like its identity; effectively the semigroup gets promoted to a monoid. Of course, this new identity element must satisfy some additional properties to make sure that the original elements of the semigroup continue to behave as before. I am wondering what the additional properties might be.

Comment: If a semigroup $S$ has no identity, just add another element not in it, call it $E$ and assign the property $Ex=xE=x$, for all $x\in S$, plus $EE=E$. Nothing else is needed. There will be no invertible element other than $E$. The submonoids will be the subsemigroups of $S$, with the addition of $E$.

Comment: @egreg Hmm. I see. Thanks. A quick question: the notion of a "semigroup homomorphism" between two such "semigroups" must change accordingly to accommodate this right? Will it be a monoid homomorphism whose pre-image over the identity is just the identity (as in only the identity of one is mapped to the identity of the other)?

Comment: If you add an identity to *all* semigroups, including monoids, then there will be no difference at all.

Comment: @egreg "No difference at all" is a bit exaggerate. For instance, a semigroup $S$ is said to be *locally trivial* if, for all idempotents $e$, $eSe = e$. If $S$ is a monoid, this property implies that $S$ is trivial.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Thank you for your input. It seems that if I choose to view semigroups as monoids with an artificially added identity, I would need to change the conditions for _local triviality_ to $e(S - \{1\})e = e$. Is there a cleaner way to view semigroups as categories then? Also, I have an unrelated question. Are you perhaps Jean-Éric Pin, author of the notes, "Mathematical Foundations of Automata Theory"?

Comment: @zeroxlr About your unrelated question, my profile should give you some evidence...

Comment: Always replacing a semigroup the monoid obtained by adjoining an identify is a bit like always replacing a locally compact space with its one point compactification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reference on this question is [1]. You may look in particular to Section 1.2, p.22 (Foundations) and p. 95, where the definition of a semigroupoid is given.

The following is a quote from this book.

> Given a semigroup S there are two popular ways to make S into a
>   monoid: $S^I$ and $S^\bullet$ (this latter is often written $S^1$).
>   The construction $S^I$ adjoins a new identity $I$ to $S$, even if $S$
>   already has an identity, whereas $S^\bullet$ adds an identity only when $S$
>   has no identity. The first is the object part of a functor
>   $\mathbf{Sgp} \to \mathbf{Mon}$, the second is not a functor; even
>   better, $S \to S^I$ is the left adjoint of the forgetful functor from
>   $\mathbf{Mon}$ to $\mathbf{Sgp}$. So (...) the construction $S \to S^I$ is the correct (or canonical) choice. This has the effect that for $G$ a group, $G^I$ is not a group. That's tough luck: from the categorical viewpoint, we cannot avoid this.

Now, another point of view is to consider semigroupoids instead of categories.
Quoting [1] p. 95,

> A semigroupoid is defined precisely like a category, but
>   one relaxes the axiom demanding identities at each object. We can view a
>   semigroup as a semigroupoid with a unique object.

[1] J. Rhodes, B. Steinberg, The $q$-theory of finite semigroups. Springer Monographs in Mathematics. *Springer, New York*, 2009. xxii+666 pp. ISBN: 978-0-387-09780-0

Comment: But if we view everything in the language of category theory (where a semigroup is then a semicategory with one element), then the forgetful functor from categories to semicategories has both a left and a right adjoint (the left being the one described here). The right is given by the Karoubi envelope.

Comment: The karoubi envelope of a semigroup without idempotents is empty

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg As it should be if it is to give a right adjoint to the forgetful functor (as there are no morphisms from a monoid to a semigroup with no idempotents).

Comment: But it means it won't serve the op's purposes. The karoubi envelope is only a good replacement for the semigroup when it has local units

Comment: @J.-E.Pin The second construction $S^*$ seems easy but I am confused about the first one. How is the construction $S^I$ different? If $S$ already has an identity $E$ and one added a new identity $I$ would they not necessarily need to be the same since by identity laws $I \cdot E = I = E$?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Ahh, yes, I know. I just thought I would mention it since the answer mentioned a left adjoint and something which was not even a functor (which might sound like there was no right adjoint functor at all, rather than just one which is not useful in this context).

Comment: @ZeroXLR The "old" identity stops being an identity in the new semigroup, since it is not the identity for the "new" identity.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah yes, of course, it makes sense now; the old identity would have been defined only for the original set and not the set with the new identity. Thank you for pointing that out. I can accept this answer now as I believe I have cleared up all my confusions.